# Floating Action Buttons Move when contenView reloaded

Tags: android, android-layout

After changing a setting I need to reload the Activity to work out if the content view needs changing. Normally I will have three floating action buttons sitting about 1/3 of the way down the screen, however most of the time after the reload one or more of the buttons disappear, or the buttons move to the top left corner.

I cannot work out if this issue is caused by how I am resetting the view of the xml for the view itself. I have noticed that either rotating your screen or bringing up the keyboard temporarily resolves the issue.

If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                android:hint="Type recipient phone number..."
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textColorHint="#aaa"
                android:backgroundTint="#fff"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/customMessage"
                android:hint="Type your emergency and hit send..."
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textColorHint="#aaa"
                android:backgroundTint="#fff"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="363dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:text="Common Emergencies"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE1"
                        android:text="Heart Attack"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE2"
                        android:text="Burns"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE3"
                        android:text="Dislocation"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE4"
                        android:text="Fainting"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE5"
                        android:text="Dizziness"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE6"
                        android:text="Fracture"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE7"
                        android:text="Flooding"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE8"
                        android:text="Fallen"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE9"
                        android:text="Bleeding"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CE10"
                        android:text="Fire"
                        android:onClick="sendText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="sendText"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewC"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="disConf"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy_white_48dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewC"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="savConf"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save_white_48dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewC"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijo8n.png)
[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lch2Y.png)

Comment: it seems like u have moved the button. can u show us ur code?

Comment: Would you like to see the layout or activity code? I can also upload a video of it happening to show I'm not moving it?

Comment: sure. it will help to solve the problem :)

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the layout xml. Please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG9FBuU1xeE for a video of the issue

Comment: i need to know what is done in your 'simple mode', if i'm not late :)

Comment: What is it you need to know about 'simple mode'. I'm not able to post any code at the moment but I can try to explain?